# SAML authentication not working properly for the roles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, forms-authentication, security-token-service

I am facing an issue regarding the authentication in SP 2010. The scenario is below:

WindowsTokenLifetime, FormsTokenLifetime and ServiceTokenLifetime are set to 365 days.

1. Login with the user on the site
2. FedAuth is created for 1 year validity.
3. Don't log out and close the browser and wait for a day or two and open the same browser again. I can find the user is logged in but his rights are not proper.
4. But I can see the FedAuth key in the browser.

Can anyone help me know what could be the reason??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution but I am not sure about the problem. I re authenticated the user on every session start for Global.asax file. Any one who find this kind of issue can look at this solution to create Global.asax file http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.dk/2011/02/handle-session-start-for-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because SharePoint 2010 also creates an auth cookie which is saved to local file. The trick is to force SharePoint 2010 to use a session-based cookie, so that it is destroyed when the page is closed. In order to do that, run the following PowerShell script on the SharePoint WFE:

```
$sts = Get­SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

Now with the SharePoint AND ADFS cookies being session based, the user can log off by simply closing their browser window.